# Can't access input variables in R Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm attempting to add a module to a preexisting R Shiny app to verify users through a cookie based system. To work with cookies in R Shiny, I've followed [this tutorial](https://calligross.de/post/using-cookie-based-authentication-with-shiny/) and I've extended shinyjs with the following javascript code:

```
shinyjs.getcookie = function(params) {
    var cookie = Cookies.get("id");
    if (typeof cookie !== "undefined") {
        Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", cookie);
    } else {
        var cookie = "";
        Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", cookie);
    }
}
shinyjs.setcookie = function(params) {
    Cookies.set("id", escape(params), {
        expires: 0.5
    });
    Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", params);
}
shinyjs.rmcookie = function(params) {
    Cookies.remove("id");
    Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", "");
}
```

I made a test example with a small R Shiny app that worked correctly without modules, however, when I tried to implement a module to perform the same function, I ran into an issue retrieving the cookies.

From within server.R, I can retrieve the cookies without issue using the following code:

```
observe({
  js$getcookie()
  print(input$jscookie)
})
```

However, when I put that same code into the module's server function, it prints out NULL every time. I believe that the problem has to do with namespaces, and that maybe `input$jscookie` in server.R refers to a different thing than `input$jscookie` in the module. However, I'm very new (just a few days) to Shiny modules, so I'm still unsure of some aspects of how they work.

Is there a way to retrieve the cookie from within the module?

Comment: When you used modules, elements in that module get the name of the module prepended to their id. So maybe your `Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", params);` is trying to refer to an input that doesn't exist. I suggest using the inspector to see what id the input actually has.

Comment: How would I use the inspector to see what id the input has? I assume you mean the inspector in the browser.

Comment: In most browsers you can right-click any element on a webpage and there should be an "inspect" option in the menu. This should then pop up a view of the page's html with the element's markup highlighted.